# What are the revolvers from Trigun called?

Tags: trigun

Do the revolvers that Vash and Knives carry in Trigun have names? Is there anything they are called individually?

Answer (score 2):

The [Internet Movie Firearms Database](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Main_Page) is the go-to source for identifying firearms in movies and other media, including anime. The [Trigun page](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Trigun#AGL_Arms_Factory_.45_Long_Colt_.28EF_Auto_Ejecting.2C_Double_Action.29_.28Vash.27s_Revolver.29) says that the pistol that Vash and Knives carries is

> a fictional double-action, full-sized revolver chambered for .45 Long Colt.

The name is AGL Arms Factory .45 Long Colt.